# Why would dapper return correct count and null values?

Tags: c#, dapper

I wanted to play around a little bit with dapper so created two classes that represent the database and a little inner join query but for whatever reason, the results are of null value. I'm new to dapper, so from what I've read in the docs and a great answer on SO ([How do I write one to many query in Dapper.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350467/how-do-i-write-one-to-many-query-in-dapper-net)), it appears I have this setup correctly. Why would the result count be correct, but the values are all null?

```
 con.Open();
    string query = @"select Orders.OrderID as OrderID,
                     Orders.OrderNumber as Orders_OrderNumber,
                     Product.ProductNumber as Product_ProductNumber,
                     Product.ProductID as Product_ProductID,
                     Product.OrderID as Product_OrderID
                     from Orders INNER JOIN Product ON Orders.OrderID = Product.OrderID WHERE Orders.OrderNumber LIKE '%" + orderNumber + "%'";
    dynamic data = con.Query<dynamic>(query);
    Slapper.AutoMapper.Configuration.AddIdentifiers(typeof(Orders), new List<string> { "OrderID" });
    Slapper.AutoMapper.Configuration.AddIdentifiers(typeof(Product), new List<string> { "ProductID" });

    var orders = (Slapper.AutoMapper.MapDynamic<Orders>(data) as IEnumerable<Orders>).ToList();
    //var orders = Slapper.AutoMapper.Map<Orders>(data);
    return orders; // count is correct but values are null
```

Classes:

```
 public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public string ProductNumber { get; set; }
    }

 public class Orders
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd imagine your mapper isn't working as expected. Step into your mapper and make sure it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be 
`Orders.OrderNumber as Orders_OrderNumber` the failure point. Try `Orders.OrderNumber as OrderNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Best practices with using Auto Mappers are Assert Statements,especially in case of Dynamic object mapping. See this [example](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping). Might help you find problem.

Additionally, taking a peek at Mapper Source code below :

```
public TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source, Action<IMappingOperationOptions> opts)
    {
        var mappedObject = default(TDestination);
        if (source != null)
        {
            var sourceType = source.GetType();
            var destinationType = typeof(TDestination);

            mappedObject = (TDestination)Map(source, sourceType, destinationType, opts);
        }
        return mappedObject;
    }
```

It seems it will return default value of T when an Empty Collection is returned.