# Filling one to many relationship using using Dapper or via Linq

Tags: c#, linq, one-to-many, dapper

Entity - `AllSalesTerritory` contains `List<MySalesPerson>` representing one to many relationship. I have `Sql` query to fetch the data where the two entities are mapped using a column `TerritoryId`. I use a following code to fill the entity using `Dapper micro ORM`:

```
 List<AllSalesTerritory> allSalesTerrotories = _connection.Query<AllSalesTerritory, MySalesPerson, AllSalesTerritory>
                (query, (pd, pp) =>
                {
                    pd.SalesPersons.Add(pp);
                    return pd;
                }, splitOn: "BusinessEntityId")
                .ToList();
```

`BusinessEntityId` is the beginning column for SalesPerson entity on executing the Sql statement

Challenge that I face is, this kind of code helps in easily filling one to one relation, here I get just one value in each `List<MySalesPerson>`, instead of aggregating those values in the collection, essentially the same result as that of SQL join query. I can easily resolve the issue using a simple `foreach` loop and aggregating the values for `MySalesPerson`. However, I want to figure out:

1. Can Dapper automatically help me achieve it, tried few extensions, but they did not work as expected
2. Can a Linq code do it for me, since this is somewhat reverse of a `SelectMany` on an entity with one to many relationship

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write one to many query in Dapper.Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350467/how-do-i-write-one-to-many-query-in-dapper-net)

Comment: I have tried Slapper.Automapper mentioned in the link you have referred, but its not working as expected, leading to aborting the call inside the dapper extension binary, without much exception information to debug

Comment: I personally have never used Slapper.AutoMapper, but though that question is definitely a duplicate.  It even has dictionary answers like mine.  Also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6380756/302918) is related and from one of the creators of Dapper.

Comment: Thanks @juharr, Sam's solution worked for me out of the box with a minor modification to handle the null key when GroupBy is done, else the Dictionary was failing for the null key

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to keep track of the unique `AllSalesTerritory` objects.  Assuming that the `TerritoryId` property is an `int` this would work.

```
var territories = new Dictionary<int, AllSalesTerritory>()
_connection.Query<AllSalesTerritory, MySalesPerson, AllSalesTerritory>
    (query, (pd, pp) =>
    {
        AllSalesTerritory territory;
        if(!territories.TryGetValue(pd.TerritoryId, out territory))
        {
            territories.Add(pd.TerritoryId, territory = pd);
        }       

        territory.SalesPersons.Add(pp);
        return territory;
    }, splitOn: "BusinessEntityId");

List<AllSalesTerritory> allSalesTerrotories = territories.Values.ToList();
```

Basically what happens here is that Dapper will return one `AllSalesTerritory` and one `MySalesPerson` for each row in the results of your query.  We then use a dictionary to see if the current `AllSalesTerritory` (`pd`) has been seen before based on the `TerritoryId`.  If so then the local `territory` variable is assigned the reference to that object.  If not then we assign `pd` to `territory` and then add that to the dictionary.  Then we just add the current `MySalesPerson` (`pp`) to the `territory.SalesPersons` list.

Comment: Thanks it does work, let me see if I can get a response for Dapper directly handling the issue, but one question, though I am not using Dictionary, but your solution is also declaring AllSalesTerritory as a local variable, then how does it aggregate the SalesPerson internally in the mapping function. We are even fetching it from dictionary except the first time. I am surely missing something out here

Comment: That's what the dictionary is for.  It keeps track of the unique `AllSalesTerritory` items.  I'll add some description to the answer.

Comment: Got it thanks a lot, I completely missed out the "out territory" inside TryGetValue, which does the job of reference assignment, so its local only for the first time during assignment to the dictionary and thereon it is fetched using dictionary and in fact that's why probably we are not using the result of _connection.Query, which would lead to similar result as my question

Comment: If I get a solution via Dapper, then that shall provide this as a result of _connection.Query. I will wait for sometime for a pure Dapper answer, before marking yours as a correct answer, thanks for the help

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a more native way to do this in Dapper.  Also the results of the `Query` would contain the correct  objects, but there would be duplicate references.