# How to map objects when using Dapper SplitOn?

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a stored proc that returns multiple rows which the following columns:

```
Guid,
Guid,
Name,
Guid,
Description
```

The first `Guid` column is always the same for all the rows. So I created the following classes:

```
public class Header
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Result 
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Header> Headers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Content> Content { get; set; }
}
```

And to get the reults I'm trying to do:

```
var result connection.Query<Guid, Header, Content>("myproc", 
    new { criteria }, 
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,
    map: ,
    splitOn: "Guid").AsList();
```

But what should I do in the `map` parameter to split the results into the objects?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can call 3 of the 5 columns returned with the same name (`Guid`) and expect Dapper to figure out how to split correctly.

Assuming that the column names returned from the SPROC are unique (I've named `Guid1`, `Guid2` and `Guid3`), we split on `Guid2` (header) and `Guid2` (content).

Since the Query will return one row per row returned from the Proc, we need to consolidate and group by the Parent Guid.

I've used the [Dictionary pattern here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32829086/) to do this rollup:

```
var sql = "EXEC p_myProc";
var resultDictionary = new Dictionary<Guid, Result>();
var results = connection.Query<Result, Header, Content, Result>(
        sql,
        (result, header, content) =>
        {
            if (!resultDictionary.TryGetValue(result.Guid1, out var existingResult))
            {
                result.Headers = new List<Header>();
                result.Content = new List<Content>();
                resultDictionary.Add(result.Guid1, result);
                existingResult = result;
            }
            // Noting OP has defined the Child tables as immutable IEnumerable<>
            (existingResult.Headers as List<Header>).Add(header);
            (existingResult.Content as List<Content>).Add(content);
            return existingResult;
        },
        splitOn: "Guid2,Guid3")
    .Distinct() // Strip duplicates by reference equality
    .ToList();
```

Note that the results returned by `Query` will have as many rows as the proc returns, but because we'll return the same reference `Result` for each `Guid1` key, `Distinct()` will strip out the duplicates.

An alternative to this approach would be to map the flattened result of the Stored Proc into a 1:1 temporary DTO POCO with all 5 columns, and then use LINQ in memory to GroupBy the `Guid1` in order to project out the `Header` and `Content` children.