# How to do a query from an object with a list of objects in Dapper C#

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

Suppose I have the following tables:

```
tb_1: |user_id|user_name|email|age|

tb_2: |item_id|item_name|value|

tb_3: |user_id|item_id|
```

And I have the models below:

Item:

```
public class Item {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Value {get; set;}
}
```

User:

```
public class User {
    public Guid UserId {get; set;}
    public List<Item> Itens {get; set;}
}
```

I am using the following Query to do the search:

```
using(var connection = ...)
{
    var query1 = "SELECT ... FROM tb_1";
    var query2 = "SELECT ... FROM tb_2 JOIN tb_3 ON ... WHERE tb_3.user_id = @UserId";
    var users = await connection.QueryAsync<User>(query1);
    foreach(var user in users)
    {
        user.Itens = await connection.QueryAsync<Item>(query2, user.UserId);
    }
    return users;
}
```

Is it possible to remove the foreach and use only one query?

PS: The tables are N to N.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct use of Multimapping in Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472088/correct-use-of-multimapping-in-dapper)

Comment: The example you put on the link is different, in case the link is 1-N and mine is N-N.

Comment: Would be the same question? Link: [Many to Many Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956443/multilevels-mapping-dapper-using-spliton)

Comment: No, they're different questions. I'd like a way that does not use the foreach. In the question you submitted the solution uses the foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. I researched and I found a solution in Dapper documentation from the "one to many" query.

```
string sql = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Orders AS A INNER JOIN OrderDetails AS B ON A.OrderID = B.OrderID;";

using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=SqlCe_W3Schools.sdf"))
{           
    var orderDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Order>();


    var list = connection.Query<Order, OrderDetail, Order>(
    sql,
    (order, orderDetail) =>
    {
        Order orderEntry;

        if (!orderDictionary.TryGetValue(order.OrderID, out orderEntry))
        {
        orderEntry = order;
        orderEntry.OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
        orderDictionary.Add(orderEntry.OrderID, orderEntry);
        }

        orderEntry.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);
        return orderEntry;
    },
    splitOn: "OrderID")
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(list.Count);

    FiddleHelper.WriteTable(list);
    FiddleHelper.WriteTable(list.First().OrderDetails);
}
```

Reference: [Query Multi-Mapping (One to Many)](https://dapper-tutorial.net/query)

Answer (score -1):

I would say "yes, but: rewrite the query to use a join", i.e.

```cs
var query = @"
SELECT ... FROM tb_1

SELECT ... FROM tb_2 JOIN tb_3 ON ... 
INNER JOIN (SELECT UserId FROM tb_1) x -- your original query here
    on tb_3.user_id = x.UserId   -- but as a sub-query
";
```

then use `QueryMultiple`. This returns two *grids*, so you'll need to read *twice* - then group and partition at the call-site.

```cs
using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, ...))
{
    var users = multi.Read<User>().AsList();
    var allItems = multi.Read<Item>().AsList();

    var usersById = users.ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
    foreach(var item in allItems) {
        usersById[item.UserId].Items.Add(item);
    }
    return users;
}
```

Comment: I would like to know if is remove thhe foreach. I will edit my question.

Comment: @ViniciusCastro the foreach there is just the fixup - it is only one query