# Anonymous type to List of object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, collections, dapper

I'm using dapper to get data from database which looks as follows (SQL Server)

```
Column1                 column2                                    column3
Type1        (1,sub1,sub1 descreption),(2,sub2,sub2 description)    test
Type2        (3,sub3,sub3 descreption),(4,sub4,sub4 description)    test
```

Classes looks as follows:

```
public class Types
{
   public string Column1 { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Subs> Column2 { get; set; }
   public string Column3 { get; set; }
}

public class Subs
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string description { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to cast Column2 as IEnumerable and unable to do so. Can someone suggest a way to do it? Do i need to change the way how data is selected from database?

Comment: subs have three properties but there are 4 comma-separated values in each `(1,sub1,sub1 description)` can you describe how should the cat be done. and by the way, column 2 should be a table itself with many relations with your current table and what you are currently doing is a very bad practice and can have many downsides

Comment: @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani Is there a better way to do the same thing? I'm open to change the implementation as well. Also, There's only 3 comma seperated values in column 2.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, column 2 should be a table itself with many relations with your current table and what you are currently doing is a very bad practice and can have many downsides.

**The right way**: Create a table that has Types table Id as foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE Subs(
id int,
typeId int foreign key references [Types](id), // you must also add an id could to Types table
name nvarchar(128), //any size that you need it
description nvarchar(max)
)
```

and the class:

```
public class Sub
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public int typeId {get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string description { get; set; }
}
```

For how to get one to many relationships with dapper, please see this question:[How to query an object with one-to-many relationship using Dapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64348120/how-to-query-an-object-with-one-to-many-relationship-using-dapper)

Comment: I would have been more clearer. It's separate table only, Problem is how to select and cast data into c#

Comment: please have a look at my edited answer.