# How to query a table and map all the related tables using Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I want to write a query for the API to get all desired data as JSON while keeping all related tables in the final result. I studied [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64348120/how-to-query-an-object-with-one-to-many-relationship-using-dapper) but I could not implement it in my case. I have the following model:

**Equipment.cs**

```
public class Equipment
{
    [Key]
    public long EquipmentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EquipmentCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EquipmentTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    //Navigation properties
    [Required]
    public int CostCenterId { get; set; }
    public CostCenter CostCenter { get; set; }
    public int? EquipmentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public EquipmentCategory? EquipmentCategory { get; set; }
    public int EquipmentTypeId { get; set; }
    public EquipmentType equipmentType { get; set; }
}
```

**CostCenter.cs**

```
public class CostCenter
{
    [Key]
    public int CostCenterId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;


    //Navigation properties
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<Equipment>? Equipments { get; set; }
}
```

**EquipmentCategory.cs**

```
public class EquipmentCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int EquipmentCategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string CategoryCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    //Navigation property
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<Equipment>? Equipments { get; set; }
}
```

**EquipmentType.cs**

```
public class EquipmentType
{
    [Key]
    public int EquipmentTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string EquipmentTypeTitle { get; set; }

    //Navigation property
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<Equipment>? Equipments { get; set; }
}
```

I use the following codes in the controller:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM Equipments INNER JOIN CostCenters ON CostCenters.CostCenterId = Equipments.CostCenterId  WHERE  EquipmentCode LIKE '1101%'"

var result = connection.Query<Equipment>(query).ToList();

return Ok(result);
```

Comment: `SELECT *` is nearly always the wrong query.  Select the fields you actually need.  If you follow this pattern on your 'user' table, you may be returning secrets, such as password/hash/salt, which is very wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to join all tables and then map the relations to `Equipment` object like this:

```cs
var query = @"
    SELECT * FROM Equipments
    INNER JOIN CostCenters ON CostCenters.CostCenterId = Equipments.CostCenterId  
    INNER JOIN EquipmentCategories ec ON Equipments.EquipmentCategoryId = ec.EquipmentCategoryId 
    INNER JOIN EquipmentTypes t ON Equipments.EquipmentTypeId = t.EquipmentTypeId
    WHERE EquipmentCode LIKE '1101%'";

var result = connection
    .Query<Equipment, CostCenter, EquipmentCategory, EquipmentType, Equipment>(
        query,
        (equipment, center, category, type) => {
            equipment.CostCenter = center;
            equipment.EquipmentCategory = category;
            equipment.EquipmentType = type;
            return equipment;
        })
    .ToList();

return Ok(result);
```