# Is there a way of using MultiMapping and QueryMultiple together in Dapper?

Tags: dapper

I have a few queries that I need to run together and I can do so using the *QueryMultiple* feature.

But in this case I've not been able to find out how could I use *MultiMapping*.

Does anyone know a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for though it's hard to tell without an example of the query you are trying to execute.

```
var sql = @"Select * 
            From Parent 
            Left Join Child on Child.ParentID = Parent.ParentID 
            Where Parent.ParentID = @id
            ... more queries";

using(var reader = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new {id=selectedId}))
{
    var stuff = reader.Read<Parent, Child, Parent>(
        (p,c)=> 
        {
            p.Child = c;
            return p;
        }, splitOn: "ChildId").Single();
    // Continue to read from the other queries in your sql.
}
```

Basically the `Read` method of the `SqlMapper.GridReader` is similar to the `Query` extension method.  You only get the `splitOn` parameter with one of the overloads that takes more than two generic types.

Comment: Am I right in saying that there is no async overload for GridReader.Read<>?

Answer (score 1):

Theres a quick example taken from another thread: [how-to-get-values-for-child-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10242703/1028323)

```
var sql = 
@"
select * from PROFILES where profileId= @id
select * from PROFILEIMAGES where OWNER_PROFILESIDFK = @id";

using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new {id=selectedId}))
{
   var profile = multi.Read<Models.PROFILE>().Single();
   profile.ProfileImages = multi.Read<Model.PROFILEIMAGES>().ToList();
}
```

Each query returns a set of objects which then can be mapped to your entities.

Comment: Thank you Alex. But I'm looking for a way of using the [Multimapping](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Tests/Tests.cs#L459) feature

Comment: Could you provide an example on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Basically I store some fields denormalized in SQL (eg: a DTags field where I have all the tags separated by ";", etc). And when I use the QueryMultiple (Read method) there's no option to use the "split" parameter as in the MultiMapping queries

Comment: What if you need to return a list of profiles?  Single() won't return as List<T>.

Comment: @johnny See juharr's example with multi mapping.