# Dapper.NET filling a class in "list of class"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dapper

I am new on Dapper.NET kinda stuck on this. I am trying to fill a class which has another class from multirow result set.

# DATABASE SP >

```
SELECT b.BuildingId, b.BuildingName, b.Wood, b.Food, b.Stone, b.Gold FROM UserBuildings ub, Buildings b WHERE b.BuildingId = ub.BuildingId AND UserId = @UserId
```

# CODE >

```
    using (IDbConnection connection = OpenConnection())
    {
        List<Building.Building> buildings = new List<Building.Building>();

        var multi = connection.QueryMultiple<Building.Building, Resource.Resource>("UserBuildingGet", new { UserId = UserId }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

        building.Resource = multi.Read<Resource.Resource>().Single();

        return building;
    }
```

# CLASSES >

```
public class Building
{
    private int _BuildingId;
    private string _BuildingName;
    private Resource.Resource _Resource;

public int BuildingId
{
    get { return _BuildingId; }
    set { _BuildingId = value; }
}
public string BuildingName
{
    get { return _BuildingName; }
    set { _BuildingName = value; }
}
public Resource.Resource Resource
{
    get { return _Resource; }
    set { _Resource = value; }
}

public Building(int BuildingId, string BuildingName, Resource.Resource Resource)
{
    this.BuildingId = BuildingId;
    this.BuildingName = BuildingName;
    this.Resource = Resource;
}
}

public class Resource
{
    private int _Wood;
    private int _Food;
    private int _Stone;
    private int _Gold;

public int Wood
{
    get { return _Wood; }
    set { _Wood = value; }
}
public int Food
{
    get { return _Food; }
    set { _Food = value; }
}
public int Stone
{
    get { return _Stone; }
    set { _Stone = value; }
}
public int Gold
{
    get { return _Gold; }
    set { _Gold = value; }
}

public Resource(int Wood, int Food, int Stone, int Gold)
{
    this.Wood = Wood;
    this.Food = Food;
    this.Stone = Stone;
    this.Gold = Gold;
}
```

}

Comment: :) yep, practice projects no need to waste ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code needs to define what separates the data. Use the `splitOn` parameter of `GridReader.Read`

```
var buildings = new List<Building.Building>();

using (IDbConnection connection = OpenConnection())
{
    using(var reader = connection.QueryMultiple("UserBuildingGet",
                                                new { UserId = UserId },
                                                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
    {
        var building = reader.Read<Building.Building,
                                   Resource.Resource,
                                   Building.Building>
            ((b, r) => { b.Resource = r; return b; }, splitOn: "Wood");

        buildings.AddRange(building);
    }
}

return buildings;
```

See: [Is there a way of using MultiMapping and QueryMultiple together in Dapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319140/is-there-a-way-of-using-multimapping-and-querymultiple-together-in-dapper)

Sample:

```
public class Building
{
    public int BuildingId { get; set; }
    public string BuildingName { get; set; }
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Id: {0} Name: {1} Resource: {2}", BuildingId, BuildingName, Resource);
    }
}

public class Resource
{
    public int Wood { get; set; }
    public int Food { get; set; }
    public int Stone { get; set; }
    public int Gold { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Wood: {0} Food: {1} Stone {2} Gold {3}", Wood, Food, Stone, Gold);
    }
}

var sql = @"SELECT 1 AS BuildingId, 'tower' AS BuildingName, 1 AS Wood, 1 AS Food, 1 AS Stone, 1 AS Gold
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 AS BuildingId, 'shed' AS BuildingName, 1 AS Wood, 1 AS Food, 1 AS Stone, 1 AS Gold";

var buildings = new List<Building>();

using(var connection = GetOpenConnection())
{
    using(var reader = connection.QueryMultiple(sql))
    {
        var building = reader.Read<Building, Resource, Building>(
            (b, r) => { b.Resource = r; return b; }, splitOn: "Wood");
        buildings.AddRange(building);
    }
}

foreach(var building in buildings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(building);
}
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'BusinessLayer.Resource.Resource' to 'BusinessLayer.Building.Building' >> in here "b.Resource = r"

I tried (Resource.Resource)(b.Resource) = r couldn't make it work. but seems gonna work just trying to test jump :(

Comment: Check my edit. It's a `Func<Building, Resource, Building>`, so I forgot to add the return.

Comment: missing ";" I guess here > { b.Resource = r; return b; } and after I fix that > Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BusinessLayer.Building.Building>' to 'BusinessLayer.Building.Building'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You didn't fully read the edit. Change `buildings.Add` to `buildings.AddRange`.

Comment: Yes! No Error! Testing asap :)

Comment: Yes, It worked really really thank you but I had to change my class like yours. what is the difference yours with mine?

Comment: Auto implemented properties were introduced in C# 3.0 See [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

Comment: I cant use this method anymore with Auto implemented properties under building :/ public Building(int BuildingId, string BuildingName, Resource.Resource Resource)

Comment: Well auto properties aren't required, but they are more convenient.

Comment: a parameterless default constructor solved the problem :) learning something everyday :)

Comment: I tend to use the [initialization syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx) more frequently than constructors.