# dapper aggregation function error

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

have this aggregation function in my code using Dapper

```
var sql = (@"SELECT *  
                  FROM [pubs].[dbo].[authors] as a
                  right join pubs.dbo.titleauthor as b 
                  ON a.au_id = b.au_idT");

 var data = connection.QueryMultiple(sql).Map<authors, titleauthor, string>(
     au=> au.au_id,
     tit=> tit.au_idT,
     (au,tits)=>{au.titleauthor=tits};);
```

there is no cast error and every objects fits well but i keep have this error

> } expected or ; expected and Invalid expression term ')'

i have no idea why. any help is appreciated.

Comment: this was taken from the solution in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379155/help-with-multi-mapper-to-create-object-hierarchy/6380756#6380756)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the `}` and `;`:

```
var data = connection.QueryMultiple(sql).Map<authors, titleauthor, string>(
     au=> au.au_id,
     tit=> tit.au_idT,
     (au,tits)=>{au.titleauthor=tits;}); // <=== this line
```

Comment: (added an example, but basically: this)