# How do you include an object that has a generic list property and a reference type property in dapper?

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-extensions

my class is:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public BankAccount Account { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
     public string Street { get; set; }
     public string City { get; set; }
     public string Zipcode { get; set; }
} 

public class BankAccount
{
      public decimal Balance {get; set;} 
      public DateTime LastDateWithdrawn { get; set;}
}
```

its not possible with multimapping or the multiple results i already tried.
How do you do that in dapper?
what I want to achieve is not to make roundtrips to the database getting the addresses and the bank account if I could use multi-mapping or multiple result or any other options.

Comment: By looking at your class, its hard to help you. Show us what you have done so far. What exactly you want to achieve ??

Comment: Okay, it means you want to get multiple results set and bind it to **Person** class right ??

Comment: @KrishnrajRana im trying to get the Person object from the database with its addresses and bank account with minimal or no roundtrips possible.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana yes but in order for me to get the addresses and bank account (both which have foreign key: PersonId) i have to get the Person object first and use its Id property. The Sample in dapper dot net website is a predetermined id of customer, orders..etc

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379155/multi-mapper-to-create-object-hierarchy#6380756) question. Dapper doesn't appear to be all that great at handling one to many relationships. The alternative seem to be a stored procedure which pulls back the addresses to the depth desired.

Comment: @m.casey Thanks! I could try some of the codes here.. looks good..

Comment: You're quite welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By read your comment, i have tried to give you answer.

Let say here you have one SP.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPersonDetail]
(
    @PersonId int
)
AS  
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

    -- 1). Get Person detail
    Select * from PersonMaster Where PersonId = @PersonId


    -- 2). Get Person Addrss
    Select * from PersonAddress Where PersonId = @PersonId

    -- 1). Get Person BankAccount
    Select * from BankAccount Where PersonId = @PersonId

End
```

and here is your dapper method which uses **QueryMultiple** method of Dapper.

```
public Person GetPersonDetail(int PersonId)
{
    try
    {
        var oPara = new DynamicParameters();
        oPara.Add("@PersonId", PersonId, dbType: DbType.Int);

        var person = new Person();
        using (var multiResults = _connection.QueryMultiple(GetPersonDetail, oPara, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
        {
            person.Person = multiResults.Read<Person>().FirstOrDefault();
            person.Addresses = multiResults.Read<Address>();
            person.BankAccount = multiResults.Read<BankAccount>().FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return person;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        thow;
    }
}
```

Hope this may help  you... All the best.

Comment: I did but im going to modify this to just a sql query i dont want any SPs in my db.. but thanks!