# Map navigation properties in Dapper.Net using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

I am using Dapper.Net to get data from SQL Server database.

Here is my POCO classes

```
public partial class Production
{
    public System.Guid ProductionId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid SurveyId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PercentComplete { get; set; }
    public string CompletedBy { get; set; }
    public string DeliverTo { get; set; }

    public virtual SurveyJob SurveyJob { get; set; }
}

 public partial class SurveyJob
 {
        public SurveyJob()
        {
            this.Productions = new HashSet<Production>();
        }

        public System.Guid SurveyId { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Status { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> JobNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> SurveyDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> RequiredBy { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Production> Productions { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get all productions along with their SurveyJob information. Here is my SQL query in the stored procedure which returns these columns

```
SELECT 
    P.ProductionId, S.SurveyId, 
    P.PercentComplete, P.CompletedBy, P.DeliverTo, 
    S.JobTitle, S.JobNumber, S.RequiredBy, S.Status, S.SurveyDate
FROM 
    dbo.Production P WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.SurveyJob S WITH(NOLOCK) ON S.SurveyId = P.SurveyId
```

Problem is that I am getting Production data but SurveyJob object is null.

Here is my c# code

```
var result = await Connection.QueryAsync<Production>("[dbo].[GetAllProductions]", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

I am getting `SurveyJob` object null as shown in image.

Need help. What I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: check this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379155/multi-mapper-to-create-object-hierarchy or do 2 queries to fill up them both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is malformed for the query you executed, your query will return a plain object (dapper will always return plain objects), so you need a class with all the properties you're selecting.

Change your model to this:

```
public partial class ProductionSurvey
{
    public System.Guid ProductionId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid SurveyId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PercentComplete { get; set; }
    public string CompletedBy { get; set; }
    public string DeliverTo { get; set; }
    public System.Guid SurveyId { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> JobNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> SurveyDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> RequiredBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nope, not with dapper, you need a model for each set of data you have.