# Multi-Mapper in Dapper one to many relations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dapper, dapper-extensions

**I am trying to get the value of my database with a relation one to many
i have my object like this**

Student

```
[Table("Student")]
    public class Student  : IStudent
    {    

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

        [Write(false)]
        public IEnumerable<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
```

Enrollment

```
[Table("Enrollment")]
    public class Enrollment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Grade { get; set; }
        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    }
```

Course

```
[Table("Course")]
public class Course
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my dapper code

```
_connection = Connect.GetOpenConnection();
        const string query = @"SELECT * FROM Student stu where id = @id " +
                             "SELECT * FROM Enrollment enr WHERE enr.StudentId in (SELECT id FROM Student stu where id = @id) " +
                             "SELECT * FROM Course cou WHERE cou.Id in (SELECT CourseId from Enrollment where StudentId = @id)";

        var result = _connection.QueryMultiple(query, new { id = id })
            .Map<Student, Enrollment, Course, int>(
                student => student.Id,     
                enrollment => enrollment.StudentId,
                course=>course.Id,
                (student, enrollments) => student.Enrollments = enrollments ,
                (student, courses) => student.Enrollments.ForEach(s=>courses.ForEach(x=>s.Course.Title = x.Title) )
            ).FirstOrDefault();
```

as per instruction [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146918/how-do-i-select-an-aggregate-object-efficiently-using-dapper) All i have to do is to extend 3 level hierarchy but i cant make it work

here is my GridReader with mapper

```
public static IEnumerable<TFirst> Map<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TKey>
        (
        this SqlMapper.GridReader reader,
        Func<TFirst, TKey> firstKey,
        Func<TSecond, TKey> secondKey,
        Func<TThird, TKey> thirdKey,
        Action<TFirst, IEnumerable<TSecond>> addSecond,
        Action<TFirst, IEnumerable<TThird>> addThird
        )
    {
        var result = reader.Read<TFirst>().ToList();

        var secondMap = reader
            .Read<TSecond>()
            .GroupBy(s=>secondKey(s))
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.AsEnumerable());

        var thirdMap = reader
           .Read<TThird>()
           .GroupBy(t => thirdKey(t))
           .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.AsEnumerable());     


        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            IEnumerable<TThird> third;
            if (thirdMap.TryGetValue(firstKey(item), out third))
            {
                addThird(item, third);
            }

            IEnumerable<TSecond> second;
            if (secondMap.TryGetValue(firstKey(item), out second))
            {
                addSecond(item, second);
            }

        }



        return result.ToList();
    }
```

when i run my app here is the result with the id of 1 notice that the Course title have no value. i hope you can help me thank you.
[image: failed]

**UPDATE 1**

I notice that i am getting the null value here, it doesnt get inside the if statement

```
IEnumerable<TSecond> second;
        if (secondMap.TryGetValue(firstKey(item), out second))
        {
            addSecond(item, second);
        }
```

**UPDATE 2**

I solve the problem here is what i do

```
var ctr = 0;
        var mapped2 = conn.QueryMultiple(query, new {id})
            .Map<Student, Enrollment, Course, int>(
                student => student.StudentId,
                enrollment => ctr = enrollment.StudentId,
                course=>course.CourseId = ctr,
                ((student, enrollments) => { student.Enrollments = enrollments; }),
                ((student, courses) => courses.ToList().ForEach(s=> student.Enrollments.ToList().ForEach(x=>x.Course = new Course
                {
                    Title = s.Title
                }))));
```

notice that i added `ctr` to get the value of `CourseId` in `enrollment => ctr = enrollment.StudentId`.
Ok now I face another problem, how to get the value of `courses`
here is my code

> ((student, courses) => courses.ToList().ForEach(s=> student.Enrollments.ToList().ForEach(x=>x.Course = new Course
>                       {
>                           Title = s.Title
>                       }))

i am only getting the last value

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM Course cou WHERE cou.Id in (SELECT CourseId from Enrollment where StudentId = 1)";` Should this be `where StudentId =  @id` ?

Comment: Also, your code shouldn't even compile: `student.Enrollments.ForEach(s=>courses.ForEach` - Your enrollment only has *one* course, so it should be `student.Enrollments.ForEach(c => c.Title = "Some course...");`

Comment: @Rob your right it should be `where StudentId = @id` typo error, i didnt get any error when i try to run my app instead i get a `null` value in Course see the screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is how i solve my problem**

As the above **UPDATE 2** details i added a variable `ctr` to get the value of `CourseId` from `Enrollment` and pass to `Course` to get the right value. After that i face another problem how to pass the value of `Course` from `Student.Enrollment.Course` here's how i figure it out.

I create a variable `var enrollLst = new List<Enrollment>();` to hold the value of `Enrollment` from the first action

```
((student, enrollments) =>
                {
                    enrollLst = enrollments.ToList();
                }),
```

Second Action

```
((student, courses) =>
                {
                    var ctrId = 0;  
                    courses.ToList().ForEach(cour =>
                    {
                        if (cour != null)
                        {
                            enrollLst[ctrId].Course = cour;
                            ctrId++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            enrollLst[ctrId].Course = null;
                            ctrId++;
                        }   
                    });
                    student.Enrollments = enrollLst;
                })).FirstOrDefault();
```

below is my whole code

```
_connection = Connect.GetOpenConnection();
        const string query = "SELECT * from Student stu where StudentId = @id  " +
                             "SELECT * from Enrollment enr where enr.StudentId in ( SELECT StudentId from Student stu where Studentid = @id)  " +
                             "SELECT * FROM Course cou WHERE cou.CourseId in (SELECT CourseId from Enrollment where StudentId = @id)";

        var enrollLst = new List<Enrollment>();
        var ctr = 0;
        var result = _connection.QueryMultiple(query, new { id })
            .Map<Student, Enrollment, Course, int>(
                student => student.StudentId,
                enrollment => ctr = enrollment.StudentId,
                course => course.CourseId = ctr,
                ((student, enrollments) =>
                {
                    enrollLst = enrollments.ToList();
                }),
                ((student, courses) =>
                {
                    var ctrId = 0;  
                    courses.ToList().ForEach(cour =>
                    {
                        if (cour != null)
                        {
                            enrollLst[ctrId].Course = cour;
                            ctrId++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            enrollLst[ctrId].Course = null;
                            ctrId++;
                        }   
                    });
                    student.Enrollments = enrollLst;
                })).FirstOrDefault();
```

GridReader with mapper extended with 3 level hierarchy as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146918/how-do-i-select-an-aggregate-object-efficiently-using-dapper)

```
public static IEnumerable<TFirst> Map<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TKey>
        (
        this SqlMapper.GridReader reader,
        Func<TFirst, TKey> firstKey,
        Func<TSecond, TKey> secondKey,
        Func<TThird, TKey> thirdKey,
        Action<TFirst, IEnumerable<TSecond>> addSecond,
        Action<TFirst, IEnumerable<TThird>> addThird
        )
    {
        var result = reader.Read<TFirst>().ToList();

        var secondMap = reader
            .Read<TSecond>()
            .GroupBy(secondKey)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.AsEnumerable());

        var thirdMap = reader
           .Read<TThird>()
           .GroupBy(thirdKey)
           .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.AsEnumerable());     

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            IEnumerable<TSecond> second;
            if (secondMap.TryGetValue(firstKey(item), out second))
            {
                addSecond(item, second);
            }

            IEnumerable<TThird> third;
            if (thirdMap.TryGetValue(firstKey(item), out third))
            {
                addThird(item, third);
            }  
        }  
        return result.ToList();
    }
```